# Wall collision and sweep and prune algorithm

Tags: collision-detection, algorithm

I am documenting myself on collision detection algorithms.

If I understand well, "sweep and prune" algorithm using frame coherence is powerful to detect object vs object collisions (almost as 0(n)).

I am wondering if this algo is good for object vs wall collision ?

Suppose you have a big plane wall that is tilted regarding the axes of the "sweep and prune" algorithm (in a 3D game), because it is tilted the bounding box is quite big, and the wall bounding box will be detected as colliding a lot of objects. Similarly if a room is tilted regarding the axes of the algo (and the room is not a cube, but a complex geometry), then all walls collides almost all objects in the room, and the "sweep and prune" algo is useless for this problem.

A turnaround could be to split the wall in many little faces before the algo ?
Or are there other fast specific algos to detect object vs (big)wall collisions ?